# Calling QgsProjectionSelector from QGIS Python plugin?

Tags: qgis, python, coordinate-system

I am trying to create a dialog that allows the user to select a coordinate system from either the recently used projections or a general list of all available projections. This would basically offer the same functionality as the standard dialog that pops up when you load in a shapefile with no known CRS.

Is there a way to call the "Coordinate Reference System Selector"-dialog from within a plugin? I know it is possible to query the recently used projections and all available projections, but it seems like a lot of overhead to recreate something that is already there in QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try something like that :

```
from qgis.gui import QgsGenericProjectionSelector

projSelector = QgsGenericProjectionSelector()
projSelector.exec_()
projSelector.selectedCrsId()
projSelector.selectedAuthId()
```

http://qgis.org/api/classQgsGenericProjectionSelector.html